# Existing 14.04 repair going on for 20 hours. Should I abort?

Tags: 14.04, recovery-mode

A couple of months ago a Windows 8.1 update locked out my existing Ubuntu 14.04. Had to let it rest for several weeks because of work issues. Last night I set up to repair it and opted for a repair and update of the OS, now it's been stuck at "Eliminating conflicting files from the operating system" for about 20 hours. Should I abort the attempt to repair and simply bite the bullet and do a fresh install? My previous installation was tuned to perfection but if need be I can do it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you can handle it. It maybe worth trying the whole repair again with a scratch free clean live cd.

Answer (score 0):

I ended aborting the installation. Found out that my complete Ubuntu install is still in place. It's just GRUB that's messed up. Now I have to find how to repair it (Boot-Repair cannot fix it, or I cannot...). Can boot Ubuntu from the advanced boot options of Win 8.1 tho. :(